# How to select a case of a table by clicking it without using id or class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

what I want to do is write code so that when we click on a cell it will change its color.

Here is the function that is supposed to do this in javascript:

```
let color = "red";
function changementColor(cell) {
     document.createElement('style').innerHTML = cell + " { background-color: " + color + "; }"
}
```

And here is where the function is called in the HTML:

```
<td class='table' onClick='changementColor(this)'></td>
```

The style created is

```
"[object HTMLTableCellElement] { background-color: red; }"
```

Comment: It's considered as a bad practice to manipulate styles manually. The right way is to toggle CSS class (and to have all styles defined in this CSS class).

Comment: yes I will try this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This of course could be refactored, but I guess this is what you want to achieve.

```js
let rows = document.querySelector("table").rows

Array.from(rows).forEach(function(row){
  let cells = row.cells;
  Array.from(cells).forEach(function(cell){
    cell.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      let el = e.target;
      el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
document.createElement('style').innerHTML = cell + " { background-color: " + color + "; }"
```

with

```
cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [two main methods](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-add-event-listener-multiple-elements-javascript/) (without using jQuery) of adding an event listener to many elements. The first is pretty similar to @marmeladze answer; the other method is to attach an event listener to something *higher up* the DOM tree (like the table instead of the td) and take advantage of [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/)

#### Attach an event handler to each table cell

First the method like marmeladze used…
but (1) I'm paranoid about creating multiple copies of the same function, one for each table cell, and (2) the iteration can be simplified by selecting the cells `<td>` rather than iterating the rows.

To ensure there's only one copy of the function, I declare it as a const right at the start.

```
const redFunc = function(e) { let el = e.target; el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; };
```

Now I select all of the table cells — I've modified the example table slightly, giving it a proper `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, and an `id` for easier selection.

```
<table id="contacts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  etc.
  </tbody>
```

Select all of the table cells at once:
`let cells = document.querySelectorAll('#contacts tbody td');`

Now attach the click handler to all of the cells:
`cells.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', redFunc));`

Those two steps can be combined, so the `cells` variable doesn't have to be created:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#contacts tbody td')
        .forEach(c => addEventListener('click', redFunc));
```

All together:

```js
const redFunc = function(e) {
  let el = e.target;
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
const activeFunc = function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
};
//document.querySelectorAll('#contacts tbody td')
//        .forEach(c => addEventListener('click', redFunc));
document.querySelectorAll('#contacts tbody td')
        .forEach(c => addEventListener('click', activeFunc));
```

```css
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tbody {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table tbody td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table th, table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table td.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="contacts">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In real life, I wouldn't manipulate the `el.style.backgroundColor` directly (as Vladimir Serykh commented on the question); I would toggle a class on the clicked cell — click adds a class, click again removes the class
`el.classList.toggle('active')`
with a CSS rule like `table td.active { background-color: red; }`
(in fact, I've gone back and made this change in the stack-snippet)

(tip: class names should describe *what* something is, or the *state* something is in, so click makes the cell "active", it doesn't make it "red", then you decide that *active* cells should be displayed in red by using a CSS rule)

…or, if you only want one cell highlighted at a time… click removes the class from all cells then adds it to the clicked cell.

#### Attach an event handler to the table

An event is handled first by the most specific thing that was clicked: the `td` table cell in this case; the event then bubbles up, to the `tr`, the `tbody` and eventually the `table`

We can attach an event handler to the *table* but then handle it only if it was a *td* that was actually clicked.
When you get an event you can get the element, and the type of that element — the `event.target.nodeName`
If that is `=== 'TD'` then we've clicked on a td element, so toggle the class of the event target node.

```
document.querySelector('table#contacts').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName === 'TD') {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

This attaches only a single event handler, not one for each `td` element, so I don't have to worry about multiple copies of my event handling function.

---

(super-experts: is my paranoia justified? or is there some way the anonymous functions get coalesced into a single copy?)